# Removing Unused Subplot in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

When using plotly (in R), after combining subplots there remains an unused and blank subplot. I've recreated the issue using the ggplot2 dataset `mpg` below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


audi <- mpg %>%
    filter(manufacturer == "audi")
chevy <- mpg %>%
    filter(manufacturer == "chevrolet")



fig1 <- plot_ly(audi, x = ~hwy, y = ~year, name = "", type = 'scatter',
             mode = "markers", marker = list(color = "blue", symbol = 'x-dot'))
fig2 <- plot_ly(chevy, x = ~hwy, y = ~year, name = "", type = 'scatter',
             mode = "markers", marker = list(color = "red", symbol = 'circle'))
fig <- subplot(fig1, fig2)
fig <- fig %>% subplot(shareX = TRUE,shareY = TRUE,which_layout = "merge")
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    title = "Audi and Chevy",
    xaxis = list(title = "Highway MPG"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Year"),
    margin = list(l = 100)
)
```

The only solution I've been able to find is tinkering with the width of the used subplot, but this leaves quite a bit of unused white space on the right and causes the title to be far off to the right (as it adjusts into the center of the used and unused subplots).

Is there a way to remove the unused subplot? If not, is there a way to organize/subset the dataframe such that only one plot needs to be used in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the colours based on the manufacturer column:

```
data.subs <- mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer == "audi" | manufacturer == "chevrolet")

fig <- plot_ly(data.subs, x = ~hwy, y = ~year, name = "",
               type = 'scatter', mode = "markers",
               marker = list(color = factor(data.subs$manufacturer,
                                           labels = c("red", "blue")),
                             symbol = 'circle'),
               text = factor(data.subs$manufacturer,
               labels = c("audi", "chevy")), hoverinfo = 'text'))

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  title = "Audi and Chevy",
  xaxis = list(title = "Highway MPG"),
  yaxis = list(title = "Year"),
  margin = list(l = 100)
)

fig
```

This makes generating multiple subplots unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks!

For my particular dataset I need different hovertext for the two categories. I.e. I need Chevy to say one thing and Audi to say another. Is there a way to do that with this method?

Comment: Same principle but in the `text`option. I've updated the answer